# How to perform custom segue across two storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue

so I inherited an old project at work that's broken up into a ton of different storyboards. While this hasn't really been too much of a hassle, the client now wants a custom segue animation that goes from a View Controller on Storyboard A to a View Controller on Storyboard B and I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I have the animation worked out if the views are on the same Storyboard, but I can't get it hooked up to a transition to another storyboard.

Comment: Have you tried right click dragging from Storyboard A to Storyboard B and pressing the show animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without using a trick, because you can't connect a segue between storyboards. You can instantiate the controller manually in the other storyboard, then do whatever custom animation you want to present or push it in code. Since the main reason for using a segue (as opposed to transitioning to the new controller in code) is that you can see the connections between your controllers in the storyboard, there's not much reason to use a segue in your case.

If you really insist on using a segue, then you need to put a "dummy" controller in your first storyboard that you connect a custom segue to. The code in that segue switches out the dummy controller for the real controller you want to segue to in the other storyboard. You can find a reference to that technique here, http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/06/multiple-ios-storyboards/.

Comment: Thank you for this! I ended up not going with a segue and just doing a custom animation and dismissing the current view without animation at the end of the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

Find below code for accessing another storyboard view:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"storyboard_A_view_identifier"]) {
      UIStoryboard *storyBoardB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyBoardB" bundle:nil];
      UIViewController *anotherViewController = [storyBoardB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard_B_view_identifier"];
      // use anotherViewController and perform custom animation on it
    }
}
```